# How to to handle unavailable tweets using Twitter API's Embedded Tweet Javascript Factory Function

Tags: javascript, twitter, promise

I am working on a Javascript web application that dynamically displays tweets based on a list of post id's returned from a database. I am using the factory function `createTweets` via the [Twitter API's Embedded Tweets Factory Function](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/embedded-tweets/guides/embedded-tweet-javascript-factory-function). Here is a simple example of how this function works:

```
twttr.widgets.createTweet(...)
.then( function( el ) {
  console.log('Tweet added.');
});
```

The function returns a promise that resolves with *either* a reference to the DOM element containing the embed, or undefined if the Tweet is unavailable. For any tweets that return undefined, the DOM isn't updated, and that way we avoid having any empty tweet boxes appear on the page. [Here is a reference](https://twittercommunity.com/t/unable-to-determine-if-embedded-tweets-are-deleted-gone-private/149025) with some further information on how that works.

My issue is that I want to be able to tell the user how many posts returned undefined so that they are aware - especially if all the tweets from the list of id's returned undefined, the user needs to know why they're seeing a blank screen - but I can't figure out how to log that on the frontend. It seems like the "undefined" response doesn't bubble up to my code. Does anyone see an obvious way I could handle this, based on the function below?

```
    // display the tweets
      twttr.widgets
        .createTweet(
          post_id_list[x].post_id,
          document.getElementById(twitter_area),
          {}
        )
        .then(function (e1) {
          window.setTimeout(hideOverlay, 5000);
          if (e1 === undefined) console.log("undefined tweet");
        })
        .catch(function (e2) {
        });
```

Comment: Well put a `if (e1 === undefined) alert("post is not available");` (or whatever else you want to do in that case) in the `then` handler? What do you mean by "*the "undefined" response doesn't bubble up to my code*"?

Comment: @Bergi thanks -  I should have included in my post that I did try that approach, and when I say that it doesn't seem to bubble up to my code, I mean that even when tweets returned undefined, if I try to log the error on the frontend (exactly as you suggested), I don't get any alerts.

Comment: "*even when tweets returned undefined*" - if you don't get that log, it would suggest that the promise returned by `createTweet` does **not** fulfill with `undefined`. Did you try logging `e1` and `e2`? Does the promise settle at all?

Comment: @Bergi thanks for your help. I did try logging `e1` and `e2`. Even when there are deleted tweets, nothing shows up in the console. It's only when I go to the network tab that I can see the 404 HTTP errors. I think I can create a minimal reproduction of the issue -- I will do that now and then post a codepen link.

Comment: Sounds like "*the Promise resolves with undefined*" is inaccurate or outdated then. It's not mentioned in the documentation, only in that comment thread.

Comment: @Bergi I think you might be right. I'm finding that even when I encounter a deleted post, the promise doesn't resolve with undefined. I'm also finding that when I try to replicate the issue in codepen, I'm able to see 100% of the posts, whereas on my app, only 80% showed up. I'm thinking either a rate limit issue or twitter is blocking the request for some reason.  I sort of have a feeling that it might be an issue with my environment since the issue doesn't happen on codepen - I'm running on a local server, maybe twitter doesn't like that, they recently started blocking web-scrapers.